# Write unwrapped array of json - Jackson

Tags: scala, jackson

how can we write unwrapped array of JsonNode in Jackson? Below is a sample code:

```
val message = """{"Type": "Type1","MessageId": "MessageId1"}"""
val msgNode = objectMapper.readTree(message)
val msgNodes = List(msgNode, msgNode).asJavaCollection
val arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode()
arrayNode.addAll(msgNodes)
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(arrayNode)
```

The above code will print array of string wrapped by square brackets something like:

```
[{"Type":"Type1","MessageId":"MessageId1"},{"Type":"Type1","MessageId":"MessageId1"}]
```

what I am looking for is unwrapped version of above, basically something like:

```
{"Type":"Type1","MessageId":"MessageId1"},{"Type":"Type1","MessageId":"MessageId1"}
```

Can someone please help? How can we extend this if the message was a POJO class and we wanted to have unwrapped output for arrays of POJO?

Comment: There are so many Scala libraries that provide a good integration with JSON ...

Answer (score 0):

You could output each item of the array and concatenate with a comma:

```scala
msgNodes
  .map(msg => objectMapper.writeValueAsString(msg))
  .mkString(",")
```

For automating this for any array inside any class, you probably have to look to other libraries that offer the possibility to describe serializer for arrays in a custom way in a specific scope (like `Writes` in Play-Json).